# php chilkat_9_5_0 extension not working in windows 10

Tags: php, windows-10, php-7.2, chilkat

My PHP Version 7.2.1 and Architecture is x86 and System is Windows 10 64 bit so I have downloaded chilkat-9.5.0-php-7.2-nts-win32 from https://www.chilkatsoft.com/php.asp#winDownloads
and extension DLL file added into my C:/xampp/php/ext such as "C:/xampp/php/ext/chilkat_9_5_0.dll" and updated my php.ini as well
But PHP is throwing startup warning and chilkat extension is not working for me could you please guide me where is i am wrong.

My php.ini

- extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
- extension=chilkat_9_5_0

PHP Error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'chilkat_9_5_0' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\chilkat_9_5_0 (The specified module could not be found.
> ), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_chilkat_9_5_0.dll (The specified module could not be found.
> )) in Unknown on line 0

[image: My php.ini]

[image: My PHP Version]

[image: My PHP extension dir]

Comment: Did you copy **both** chilkat_9_5_0.php and chilkat_9_5_0.dll to the PHP extensions directory?

Comment: I have copy only chilkat_9_5_0.dll into PHP extensions directory. Should we copy chilkat_9_5_0.php to PHP extensions directory as well as?

I have copied both files into PHP extensions directory and check again but error still there and not working.

Comment: If the error message tells you that the file `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_chilkat_9_5_0.dll` is not found, and your explorer does not display such a file, isn't that a good indicator that this file is missing?

Comment: Also, the installation documentation at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/installPhpWindows.asp tells you to use `extension=chilkat_9_5_0.dll` in php.ini (as far as I see, you forgot to add `.dll` at the end)

Answer (score 1):

well first of all you need to find if your PHP is NTS (None Thread Safe) or TS (Thread Safe) by phpinfo()

[as you can see thread safety is enabled which means that PHP is TS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKacq.png)

and my PHP version is 7.2.34 x64 which means that i have to download

chilkat PHP 7.2.* (thread-safe) x64

after installation place chilkat_9_5_0.dll in (C:\xampp\php\ext)
if you are using xamp my default require() is at (C:\xampp\php\pear)
so move chilkat_9_5_0.php to (C:\xampp\php\pear)

in the php.ini search for dynamic extension and below add ( extension=chilkat_9_5_0.dll ) with the .dll

restart XAMP and test it with the given test.php file in the downloads and it should work